# numpy matrix row to csv

Tags: arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray, csvwriter

in the code below, my intention is to copy the rows of this matrix to a csv file. I know that the csv function writer copies an array perfectly. But when the row comes from a matrix this doesn't seem to work. The csv file then looks like this ['unwanted csv-file'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtTI9.png). The numbers of one row are together in 1 place of the csv file. Each one on a separate row though, which is what I desired. But I need the numbers of 1 row seperated with commas.

This code is a simplification of the code needed for a simulation program. In which I want to copy the first row of a calculated matrix per time interval to a csv file. i in this example is replaced by time t and so each time the first row is sent to file1, second row to file2 and so on. But when I can solve the problem for this code, I can solve it for my simulation program as well.

```
import numpy as np 
import csv
import pandas as pd 

V = np.matrix([[ 8.12500000e-03+4.12066060e-02j, -4.02435390e-18+9.30274988e-19j, -5.41422932e-18+4.03695160e-19j],
                [-7.21532153e-18+7.93138177e-19j,  8.12500000e-03+4.12066060e-02j, -6.50521303e-18+4.33680869e-18j], 
                [-7.09036473e-18+5.11438288e-19j, -6.50521303e-18+4.33680869e-18j, 8.12500000e-03+4.12066060e-02j]]) 

path = 'C:/Users/Gebruiker/OneDrive/Documenten/'
for i in range(0,3): 
    if i ==0: 
        with open(path + 'test12345678911.csv', mode='w', newline='') as voltage_file_a: 
            voltage_writer_a = csv.writer(voltage_file_a, delimiter=';', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
            row = np.array(abs(V[i,:]))
            voltage_writer_a.writerow(row)
    else: 
        with open(path + 'test12345678911.csv', mode = 'a', newline = '') as voltage_file_a:
            voltage_writer_a = csv.writer(voltage_file_a, delimiter=';', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
            row = np.array(abs(V[i,:]))
            voltage_writer_a.writerow(row)
```

I tried to solve this with the step 'row = np.array...' but this doesn't help. Has someone an idea how to convert the row of the matrix to the csv file.

This code results in the following csv-file:
[unwanted csv-file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtTI9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some Commands that may be useful in this solution:

```
np.matrix.ravel()
np.matrix.flatten()
np.matrix.tolist()
```

In your example, replace the `np.matrix` with `V`.